# Error en webservices java

Tags: java, json, webservice, rest

Tengo un webservice en Java que recibe un Json y lo tiene que insertar en una tabla. El problema es que me esta arrojando un error que no he podido solventar.
En primera instancia pensé que era el valor "contenido" del Json porque lo tenia que guardar en una columna tipo blob pero intente guardar ese valor en una columna varchar(1000) y me sigue dando el mismo error.
Ya no se que mas intentar, este fragmento de código lo he utilizado en otros proyectos con Json y nunca me había fallado.

El JSON

```
{
"status": "ok",
"message": "datos obtenidos correctamente",
"data": {
    "nroFolio": "123456789",
    "idEspecieValorada": "123456789",
    "contenido": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<datosImpresionTOList>\n    <datosImpresionTO>\n        <basedest>LOS ANGELES</basedest>\n        <bd>LSQ</bd>\n        <c01></c01>\n        <c02></c02>\n        <c03></c03>\n        <c04></c04>\n        <c128_cb28l>5330066881571030013301083025</c128_cb28l>\n        <c39_os>6688157103</c39_os>\n        <cbl28>5330066881571030013301083025</cbl28>\n        <cde>8302</cde>\n        <comuna>ANTUCO</comuna>\n        <contacto_dest>CRISTIAN ROMERO</contacto_dest>\n        <cta_cte>96801150-11-8</cta_cte>\n        <detcod01></detcod01>\n        <detcod02></detcod02>\n        <detcod03></detcod03>\n        <detcod04></detcod04>\n        <detcod05></detcod05>\n        <detdd01></detdd01>\n        <detdd02></detdd02>\n        <detdd03></detdd03>\n        <detdd04></detdd04>\n        <detdd05></detdd05>\n        <detdd06></detdd06>\n        <detdd07></detdd07>\n        <detdd08></detdd08>\n        <dims>25,7 x 25,7 x 25,7 CM</dims>\n        <dir_dest1>CAUPOLICAN 123</di...",
    "idGuias": "GUIA",
    "nombreArchivo": "template_guia_landscape.jasper",
    "rutaArchivo": "/home/l101/Proyectos java/asdasd asdasd/asd/asd/asd/sad/asd/",
    "tipo": "LASER"
}}
```

El JAVA

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public jsonResultResponse postEtiqueta(List<ResponseBxe> data) throws ParseException, SQLException {

    Conexion con = new Conexion("DESA");
    Connection miCon = con.GetConnection();

    jsonResultResponse result = new jsonResultResponse();
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            ResponseBxe response = new ResponseBxe();

            response.setNroFolio(data.get(i).getNroFolio());
            response.setIdEspecieValorada(data.get(i).getIdEspecieValorada());
            response.setContenido(data.get(i).getContenido());
            response.setIdGuias(data.get(i).getIdGuias());
            response.setNombreArchivo(data.get(i).getNombreArchivo());
            response.setRutaArchivo(data.get(i).getRutaArchivo());
            response.setTipo(data.get(i).getTipo());

            String query = "INSERT INTO NOMBRETABLA (N_FOLIO, ID_ESPECIE_VAL, CONTENIDO, ID_GUIA, NOM_ARCHIVO, RUTA_ARCHIVO, TIPO) "
                    + "VALUES('" + response.getNroFolio() + "' ,'" + response.getIdEspecieValorada() + "','" + response.getContenido() + "','" + response.getIdGuias() + "','" + response.getNombreArchivo() + "','" + response.getRutaArchivo() + "','" + response.getTipo() + "')";
            prep = miCon.prepareStatement(query);
            prep.executeQuery();
            prep.close();
        }

        result.setCode(200);
        result.setStatus("OK");
        result.setMessage("Datos insertados correctamente!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        result.setCode(401);
        result.setStatus("Error");
        result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result.setCode(300);
        result.setStatus("Error");
        result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (prep != null) {
            try {
                prep.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                result.setCode(400);
                result.setStatus("Error");
                result.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

El ERROR

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Payara Server 5.181 #badassfish - Error report</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error</h1>
    <hr />
    <p><b>type</b> Exception report</p>
    <p><b>message</b>Internal Server Error</p>
    <p><b>description</b>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</p>
    <p><b>exception</b>
        <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.</pre>
    </p>
    <p><b>root cause</b>
        <pre>javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.</pre>
    </p>
    <p><b>root cause</b>
        <pre>javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can&#39;t infer a type for unmarshalling into: java.util.List</pre>
    </p>
    <p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the Payara Server
            5.181 #badassfish logs.</u></p>
    <hr />
    <h3>Payara Server 5.181 #badassfish</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Ha intentado usar `ArrayList` o `LinkedList` en lugar de `List` en el parámetro del método? El mensaje de «Cannot infer a type for unmarshalling into: java.util.List» podría indicar que se está intentando instanciar un objeto a partir de `java.util.List`, pero esto no sería posible porque es una interfaz. `ArrayList` o `LinkedList` son clases y sí podrían ser instanciables.

Comment: Toda la razón, lo puse ArrayList y funciono!!. Gracias

Comment: Rayos pero no esta almacenando nada....